# Encrypt a pdf using openssl private key - PHP

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-4, openssl, public-key-encryption

Is there a possibility to encrypt a PDF using openssl private/public key in PHP?
Appreciate if you can provide an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You would encrypt it with a public key and decrypt it with the private key.

As per [this blog post](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide), I recommend using PHPSecLib instead of interfacing with OpenSSL directly, as there are a lot of things that can go wrong. In particular: padding oracle attacks.